# socket.sendUrgentData doesn't work in android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I use a thread to test is socket connect every 5 second 
but sendUrgentData doesn't work 
this is my code

```
class CheckSocketThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        boolean SocketConnect = true;
        while(SocketConnect){
            try{
                mSocket.sendUrgentData(0xFF);
                System.out.println("socket still connect");
                Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("socket disconnect");
                SocketConnect = false;
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I star the server activity and client activity

logcat will show `socket still connect` every 5s

but when I down the server, it still show `socket still connect` every 5s

will not show `socket disconnect` , what's wrong on my code?

Comment: Try it 8193 times. There is a socket send buffer.

Comment: try sendUrgentData 8193 times in a single while loop?

Comment: use `for(i = 0 ; i < 9005 ; i++){
                  mSocket.sendUrgentData(0xFF); 
                  if(i%1000==0)
                   System.out.println(i);
                 }`  it still can't work